# Add .vs folder to the global ignore list in Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2015, tortoisesvn

Visual Studio 2015 is automatically creating a folder called ".vs" within my solution folder. I do not want to add this folder to source control and therefore would like to add the folder ".vs" to the Tortoise SVN global ignore list.

I have tried adding .vs to the ignore list but it did not ignore the folder. I assume adding .vs ignored all files with the extension .vs. How can I ignore the folder .vs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did something wrong because setting `svn:ignore` to `.vs` at the solution level will ignore the directory and its contents. Note that `svn:ignore` **ignores unversioned items only** so if the `.vs` directory has been already added to the repository then you have to remove it first.

Moreover, you should use Subversion integration plug-in such as VisualSVN or AnkhSVN with Visual Studio. I don't know about AnkhSVN but VisualSVN configures to ignore `.vs` by default.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the svn:ignore only applied to unversioned items.

Answer (score 3):

The question asked to use Tortoise SVN and 'without adding this folder to source control'
This answer is tailored to the Tortoise GUI.

Right click on a svn folder, click Tortoise settings, and then in the General settings you can enter in the global ignore pattern GUI field.

Use regular expression square brackets to start a folder with a "." (dot)

```
[.]vs
```